# Why is the `EVP_get_cipherbyname` symbol exported only on some Android devices?

Tags: android, android-ndk, dynamic-linking

I have an app built with Qt for Android. The app is shipped with a custom built openssl version. This works on most devices, however, on a couple of devices it crashes as soon as an https request is done.

One example is the SAMSUNG-SM-G930AZ, API Level 26 (Android 8.0).

It produces the following trace when crashing.

```
backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000000000667c4  /system/lib64/libc.so (strcasecmp+8)
    #01 pc 000000000023ddd0  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (EVP_get_cipherbyname+24)
    #02 pc 000000000003a5f0  /data/app/ch.opengis.qfield_beta-ojJ20GzjLOx-tvpq9AD27A==/lib/arm64/libssl_1_1.so (offset 0x29000)
```

I downloaded the `libandroid_runtime.so` file from this device where it lists the mentioned symbol

```
readelf -Ws libandroid_runtime.so | grep EVP_get_cipherbyname
  3593: 000000000023dd78   336 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 EVP_get_cipherbyname
```

On another (not crashing SM-T580, Android 8.1) this is not the case

```
readelf -Ws /tmp/libandroid_runtime.so | grep EVP_get_cipherbyname
```

This symbol is also in `libcrypto_1_1.so` which is shipped with the app. I assume this collision is responsible for the crash.

In the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes) the following NDK change was done with Android 7:

> In order to reduce the impact that this restriction may have on currently released apps, a set of libraries that see significant use—such as `libandroid_runtime.so`, [...] — are temporarily accessible on Android 7.0 (API level 24) for apps targeting API level 23 or lower.

The app targets API level 29, so I assume this library should not be available to this app.

How can this crash be avoided?
Can it be prevented from loading `libandroid_runtime.so` or can openssl be compiled with specific flags or is a completely different approach required?